# Jasmine: How to test a controller function calling other javascript function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Here is the sample code:

```
App.controller('Crtl', ["$scope", function ($scope) {

$scope.FetchDetail = function () {
    var accNum = this.customer.accNo;
    GetAccountDetails(accNum);
}; }]);
```

I am new to Jasmine and right now I am writing unit tests for my angular code. Here I created FetchDetail function which then calls javascript function GetAccountDetails(accNum).

How can I test this sample using Jasmine.

Comment: Where is `GetAccountDetails()` defined? Is it injected?

Comment: It is defined in another Javascript file.

Comment: So it is a global? You are better off injecting it and then you can stub it, but you can put a spy on it. I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you need to stub it (i.e. capture and change its behaviour) or if it is enough to spy on it (watch it). Either way, you would be better off injecting it, so you can control it.

I have been using sinon http://sinonjs.org quite happily.

If you want to *spy* on it, i.e. watch its behaviour without changing it, then before calling it, you would do

```
var spy = sinon.spy(GetAccountDetails);
```

Then you can check if it was called, or what arguments were, etc.

```
spy.calledOnce === true; // if it was called once
spy.called === true; // if it was called at all
spy.firstCall.args[0]; // first argument to first call
// etc. - check out the docs
```

If you need to stub it, use the stub functionality, where you can then define what the behaviour *should* be. You get all of the spying features, but also control what the response is. However, it is hard to spy on a global, as opposed to a method of an existing object.

Comment: A pleasure. If you get stuck with it, post another q. FYI, important track is `spy.reset()` which resets the call count. I use it in `beforeEach()` so that each invocation I know exactly how many calls there should be and what args.

Comment: @deitch Should `GetAccountDetails` be defined on scope? I have it defined on the `this` of the same controller and Karma gives a `ReferenceError: GetAccountDetails is not defined` error!! Please suggest.

Comment: @Dravidian unsure. If it is defined on `this`, then the OP's example wouldn't work as it would need to be `this.GetAccountDetails()`. In general, I avoid globals as much as is humanly possible (and a wee bit more), and have tried to be as functional as possible (no `this` when I can get away with it).